# Not able to install phpMyAdmin on CentOS7

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos7, php-7.2

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin for CentOS 7 with the following command:

```
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

I then get the following message:

```
Error: php72u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

If I try with --skip-broken it will not install phpMyAdmin

This is my installed php:

```
yum list installed *php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.uninett.no
 * epel: mirror.nsc.liu.se
 * extras: ftp.uninett.no
 * ius: lon.mirror.rackspace.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.ukfast.co.uk
 * updates: ftp.uninett.no
Installed Packages
mod_php72u.x86_64                                                                                7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-cli.x86_64                                                                                7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-common.x86_64                                                                             7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-devel.x86_64                                                                              7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-gd.x86_64                                                                                 7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-mysqlnd.x86_64                                                                            7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-opcache.x86_64                                                                            7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-pdo.x86_64                                                                                7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
php72u-xml.x86_64                                                                                7.2.8-1.ius.centos7                                                                             @ius
```

I have tried uninstalling php and installing php 7.2 again many times, but with the same error. I can't find where the php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 file is or why it's installed?

Anyone know what I should try?

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect phpMyAdmin in EPEL (version 4.4) to work with recent PHP versions.
You need at least 4.8 which includes some 7.2 specific fix.

So you have to do a manual install or switch your packages provider.

Comment: I see! Thanks, I will try to look into that :)